# I want to combine multiple Excel files

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, data-transfer, data-analysis

I need assistance with the issue that I have multiple Excel files which are being updated on daily basis but for the analysis part I have to combine them all; and then perform the analysis.

Is there any way to automate this process, where all the data from the excel files will be copied to a single excel file.

All kinds of solutions welcome. I can't use Google sheets.

Comment: You can reference cells in other files in your formulas. Maybe that's easier.

Comment: Where is the real time part? Once a day doesn't required real time

Answer (score 1):

Try adding macros, like this one to combine multiple Excel files

```
Sub MergeExcelFiles()
Dim fnameList, fnameCurFile As Variant
Dim countFiles, countSheets As Integer
Dim wksCurSheet As Worksheet
Dim wbkCurBook, wbkSrcBook As Workbook

fnameList = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Microsoft Excel Workbooks 
(*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm),*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm", Title:="Choose Excel files to merge", 
MultiSelect:=True)

If (vbBoolean <> VarType(fnameList)) Then

    If (UBound(fnameList) > 0) Then
        countFiles = 0
        countSheets = 0

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

        Set wbkCurBook = ActiveWorkbook

        For Each fnameCurFile In fnameList
            countFiles = countFiles + 1

            Set wbkSrcBook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=fnameCurFile)

            For Each wksCurSheet In wbkSrcBook.Sheets
                countSheets = countSheets + 1
                wksCurSheet.Copy after:=wbkCurBook.Sheets(wbkCurBook.Sheets.Count)
            Next

            wbkSrcBook.Close SaveChanges:=False

        Next

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

        MsgBox "Processed " & countFiles & " files" & vbCrLf & "Merged " & countSheets & " worksheets", Title:="Merge Excel files"
    End If

Else
    MsgBox "No files selected", Title:="Merge Excel files"
End If
End Sub
```